# missing required root key on github actions

Tags: yaml, github-actions

I have added Machine Learning Model and preceding with CI pipeline in Github, however while executing workflow, I am getting error for Missing required root key on. Below is my yml file code.

```
ci_pipeline: 
       on:
        push:
        branches:
          - main
       
       steps:
        - uses: actions/checkout@v1
          with:
            fetch-depth: 0


        - name: Set up Python 3.9
          uses: actions/setup-python@v1
          with:
            python-version: 3.9


        - name: Install dependencies
          run: |
            python -m pip install --upgrade pip
            if [ -f requirements.txt ]; then pip install -r requirements.txt; fi


        - name: Format
          run: |
            black app.py


        - name: Lint
          run: |
            pylint --disable=R,C  app.py


        - name: Test
          run: |
            python -m pytest -vv test.py
```

Answer (score 0):

The "missing root key" error typically occurs in GitHub Actions when your workflow YAML file (e.g., .github/workflows/main.yml) is not properly formatted or lacks the required keys. To resolve this error, you need to ensure that your workflow file adheres to the correct structure and includes the necessary keys.

You may check that your YAML file is valid or not by using any online YAML validator.